# updateRadioButtons within a function

Tags: r, shiny

I have an identical call to `updateRadioButtons` appear a half dozen times within a large shiny app. It'd be nice to turn this into a function so I can make my code much cleaner, but I can't figure out how to put a worker function like updateRadioButtons inside a sub function.

Specifically I need an action button to change the value of a radio button, then have that radio button value change trigger another reactive. This example script works like it should:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("turnover","Turnover")
  ,radioButtons("team","Possession"
                ,choices = list(Home = "Home", Away = "Away"))
  ,textOutput("outText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$turnover,{
    updateRadioButtons(session,"team"
                       ,selected = ifelse(input$team == "Home"
                                          ,"Away","Home"))
  })

  output$outText = renderText({paste0("Current possessing team is: ",input$team)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But if I move updateRadioButtons into a sub-function it doesn't work anymore:

```r
library(shiny)

handle_turnover = function(input,output,session){
    updateRadioButtons(session,"team"
                       ,selected = ifelse(input$team == "Home"
                                          ,"Away","Home"))  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("turnover","Turnover")
  ,radioButtons("team","Possession"
                ,choices = list(Home = "Home", Away = "Away"))
  ,textOutput("outText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$turnover,{
    handle_turnover()
  })

  output$outText = renderText({paste0("Current possessing team is: ",input$team)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I click the `Turnover` button I get the following error

> Warning: Error in ifelse: argument "input" is missing, with no default
>   75: ifelse
>   73: handle_turnover [C:/Users/pmelg/OneDrive/Desktop/fakeapp.R#4]
>   72: observeEventHandler [C:/Users/pmelg/OneDrive/Desktop/fakeapp.R#18]
>   1: runApp

My research suggested that modules might be the way to go, so I also tried calling the handle_turnover function like so `callModule(handle_turnover(),"")` but I got the exact same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: the `handle_turnover` function needs `input` for `input$team` and `session`, but no arguments were passed to the function when called: `handle_turnover()` - this would work you passed these variables in, try: `handle_turnover(input, output, session)` - modules may be helpful in future if you plan for functions to generate UI, inputs, and outputs and tracking id's

Comment: Cripes that's so incredibly obvious once you say it!  ```handle_turnover(input, output, session)``` completely solved my problem. Thanks!